# Why does Mergelyan's theorem fail in higher dimensions?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

In complex analysis we have

Mergelyan's theorem :

Let $K$ be a compact subset of the complex plane $C$ such that $C∖K$ is connected. Then, every continuous function $f : K
\to  C$, such that the restriction $f \to int(K)$ is holomorphic, can be approximated uniformly on $K$ with polynomials. Here, $int(K)$ denotes the interior of $K$.
Mergelyan's theorem also holds for open Riemann surfaces.

But I wonder, why does this fail for several complex variables?
How to prove that it can fail in higher dimensions (spaces of several complex variables) and what are some examples of such failures ?

Comment: How do you know it even fails at all

Comment: @FShrike I read that at different places.

Comment: one such example is in a 2-page paper of J Wermer in Annals for an arc in $\mathbb C^3$; see https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969680

Comment: @Conrad I have no access to that but thanks.

Comment: there is a publicly available paper by S Gubkin (PhD thesis at OSU) with a discussion about this stuff and many other references so maybe if you look at that you can find  what you want; the Wermer example (1950's and maybe first such as otherwise I do not see why it would have been poublished in Annals of all places) is very simple but many other such have been conctoed since  - https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_olink/r/1501/10?clear=10&p10_accession_num=osu1430998320